# How to allow one directive to be used from many inputs in Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following template:

```
<md-input-container class="new-paragraph addon-menu">
    <label>Post text</label>
    <textarea ng-model="user.post" rows="3"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
<md-menu>
    <md-button aria-label="" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o mobile-menu-ic light-gray-text font-size-extra-large"></i>
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content>
        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="templateVariable in templateVariables">
            <md-button ng-click="injectVariableAtCursor(templateVariable);">{{templateVariable}}</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>                                                             
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Now, I want to insert some predefined text (**at cursor position**) to `user.post` model when user click on specific item inside `<md-menu-content>`

I know that directives with isolated scope may help here, but I'm not sure how to implement this as `input` and the buttons itself are independent, e.g. they are not wrapped under single `ngModel`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need directive for this.

If I understand your problem this will probably be enougth :

controller :

```
$scope.injectVariableAtCursor = function(templateVariable) {
 $scope.user.post = templateVariable;
};
```

Here is an example of what you want :

```js
var myController = function($scope) {
  var target = null;
  
  $scope.user = { post: "first" };
  
  $scope.handleFocus = function(event) {
    target = event.target;
  };
  
  $scope.handleClick = function(text) {
    var start, end, actual = $scope.user.post;
    
    if(target) {
      start = target.selectionStart;
      end = target.selectionEnd;
    }else{
      start = end = $scope.user.post.length;
    }
    
    
    $scope.user.post = actual.substr(0,start) + text + actual.substr(end, actual.length);
  };
  
};

angular.module('controller', [])
  .controller('myController', myController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="controller">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <textarea ng-model="user.post" ng-focus="handleFocus($event)"></textarea>
    
    <button ng-click="handleClick('bla')">add bla</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The thing I forgot to mention is that I want to inject the variable at cursor position (in input element).

Comment: sorry, deleted posted by accident... anyway, I think I found a solution, will test it and publish if acceptable... but it's interesting for me to see your idea.